# What's the best way to travel from Sao Paulo to Tiradentes?

Tags: public-transport, buses, brazil

What's the best (in my context: cheapest, by using public transport) way to travel from Sao Paulo to Tiradentes (Minas Gerais, Brazil)?

Tiradentes is a historical place, quite a small one, but it has the historical pipe organ of Brazil. I need to arrive there next week for a pipe organ recital.

There was a BlaBlaCar from Sao Paulo to Sao Joao del Rei, I tried to contact the driver and they deleted the announcement.

It seems that Rome2Rio suggests quite a long bus ride, which I will probably choose, but I'm looking for alternatives (maybe BlaBlaCar alternatives or another bus company which Rome2Rio did not index yet):

> [image]

Is there a more direct route to Tiradentes, which could be better?

Comment: Cheapest or easiest? You've asked two different things. And often the cheapest is actually the hardest (ala hitchhiking)

Comment: @MarkMayoSupportsMonica I'm not sure if I'd be walking until there I would arrive for the concert next week. :) I reworded the question a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a direct bus from Sao Paulo to Tiradentes.

Bus company [Util](https://www.util.com.br) provides several connections each day, most overnight, between Sao Paulo (Tiete) and Sao Joao del Rei, starting at 112 BRL and taking about nine hours. From there, you should be able to get a local bus to Tiradentes.

You might get lucky with a Blablacar, but don't count on it. And, keep in mind that there's a good chance the driver will not speak English.

(You could also fly to Belo Horizonte, and then get yourself to Tiradentes, but it's not likely this will be more convenient or cheap.)